# How to Hydrate custom query in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-query

After performing a custom query using

```
$DBH = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection()->getDbh();
$PDO = $DBH->prepare("mysql query");
$PDO->execute();
```

How do I return model objects instead of record arrays?

**EDIT**
I got mine working by using something like this: `$data_object = doctrine_core::getTable('table_name')->find('id_from_raw_SQL')`. Easy as pie! And thanks to Dan for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can *automatically* with a raw SQL query. You could always write your own hydrate method that creates the objects from the results.

If you want Doctrine to do it, you have to write at least the SELECT portion of the query with certain syntax to use `Doctrine_RawSql` and get hydrated objects:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/native-sql

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_rawsql.html

Comment: I create my own hydrating function then. Thanks!